# Can't get value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, constructor

Still can't understand my mistake with this code.
All what I want it - via **prompt** get all list of users (name / surname)

```js
function UserList() {
  let users = [];
  while (true) {
    let response = prompt('Please, enter your name surname?');
    if (response == null) {
      alert('cancel');
      break;
    }
    users.push(response.split(' '));
  }
  return users;
}

function User() {
  this.name = userList[0];
  this.surname = userList[1];
  this.regDate = new Date;
  for (i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) {
    console.log('Name: ' + this.name + ' Surname: ' + this.surname + '. Date of registration : ' + this.regDate)
  }
}

let userList = new UserList();
let user = new User();
```

And I faced with a misunderstanding why I cant get first word of **prompt** despite I put users.push (response.split(' ')).
userList [0] - shows first **index** of array instead first word.

And second I want to get all list of users in console.log but instead it I get the same string depending on length of array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

userList[0] in the function User will return an array: ['name', 'surname'].
To get the first name for example, you need to use this.name = userList[i][0]

```
function UserList() {
    let users = [];
    while (true) {
        let response = prompt('Please, enter your name surname?');
        if (response == null) {
            alert('cancel');
            break;
        }
        users.push(response.split(' '));
    }
    return users;
}

function User() {
    for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) {
        this.name = userList[i][0];
        this.surname = userList[i][1];
        this.regDate = new Date;
        console.log('Name: ' + this.name + ' Surname: ' + this.surname + '. Date of registration : ' + this.regDate)
    }    
}

let userList = new UserList();
let user = new User();
```

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer!

Comment: Although it ignores the fact that `User` should represent _one_ user. Iterating over the array of name inside a constructor makes no sense. @axtck

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing an array in an other array, so your index is not correct (array looks like this: `[["firstname", "lastname"]]`). You could spread the items when pushing using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`), you could also flatten the array using `flat()`.

Also when creating a date, use `new Date()`.

```js
 function UserList() {
   let users = [];
   while (true) {
     let response = prompt('Please, enter your name surname?');
     if (response == null) {
       alert('cancel');
       break;
     }
     users.push(...response.split(' ')); // flatten

   }
   return users;
 }

 function User() {
   this.name = userList[0];
   this.surname = userList[1];
   this.regDate = new Date(); // ()

   console.log('Name: ' + this.name + ' Surname: ' + 
     this.surname + '. Date of registration : ' + this.regDate)
 }

 let userList = new UserList();
 let user = new User();
```

Using `flat()`

```
return users.flat();
```

### Edit

I actually understood the question wrong (thought you only wanted 1 user), the other answer should be correct and makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

1. UserList shouldn't be a constructor. It should just be a function that returns an array of names.
2. You shouldn't be iterating over the list of users *within* `User`. You should then be iterating over the array creating *one new `User`* on each iteration which *should* be generated from a constructor. You can just pass in each name from the array and build an new object.

```js
function getNames() {
  const users = [];
  while (true) {
    const response = prompt('Please, enter your first and last names');
    if (response == null) break;
    users.push(response.split(' '));
  }
  return users;
}

// Pass in a user name from the array as an argument
// It's array so we can destructure the first and last name
// immediately
function User([first, last]) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.regDate = new Date();
  this.message = `Name: ${this.first}. Surname: ${this.last}. Date of registration: ${this.regDate}.`;
}

// Iterate over the array generated by `getUsers`
// and for each name create a new user.
for (let name of getNames()) {
  console.log(new User(name));
}
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)